# Contador de caracteres de uma h

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber com contar quantos caracteres contem dentro desta h2, que neste caso ex: `<h2 class="h2">Ola Mundo</h2>` contem 9 caracteres.

Comment: Todos <h2> vai `var contador = $('h2').length` e for com classe assim `var contador = $('h2[class*=h2]').length` é jquery.

Comment: Muito Obrigado mais uma vez Sergio !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em JavaScript as Strings têm uma propriedade `.length` que dá exatamente o que queres.

Os objetos do DOM têm uma propriedade `innerHTML` que dá o seu conteúdo (ou `innerText` caso queiras ignorar o HTML).

Combinando isso com um método que vá buscar o objeto ao DOM tens o que queres:

```
var length = document.querySelector('h2.h2').innerHTML.length;
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ryjjo0dj/